# Implementing JWT Spring Security Token Store with Hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-security, jwt, oauth-2.0

I am working on implementing my first production grade jwt token store and came across the sql for these tables, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/tests/annotation/jdbc/src/main/resources/schema.sql. Working with an in-memory jwt token store will not work for production of course. I have come across in memory token store to jdbc token store configurations. Is it possible to do this with Hibernate? Because these tables don't have PK , I guess I will create a column for Hibernate that I could autoincrement that is the primary key for the table and id for Hibernate?

Comment: I assume you need the database for client details? It's confusing because you only mentioned the JWT token store which doesn't have a database.

Comment: Thank you sir for answering my question! Yes, I realized that after doing further research. I realized that a generated token contains the signature that is validated against the secret on the server side that validates it's authenticity. I guess that makes a database not needed.

Comment: @DaveSyer, do you mind if I ask you another jwt related question? I worried about the situation of my jwt being stolen. When I researched this scenario I came across XSS attacks (cross side scripting attack). I also found that setting your jwt to a HttpOnly cookie is a good way to keep it invisible to javascript that might be injected into your site. Could you discuss this configuration in Spring? Thank you again for your time and expertise.

Comment: Tokens are not generally speaking cookies. And they shouldn't be accessible to JavaScript clients. So if I were you I'd just stick to authorization code grants and keep the cookies for session authentication (like in the tutorials I know you have been using).

Comment: Thank you Mr. Syer. I appreciate you taking the time to answer my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a database for a JWT token (the data are stored in the token). Sometimes it's useful to have an approval store, but that's a different concern. I wouldn't use hibernate for that if I were you but there's nothing stopping you.